# What are the best resources for learning Windows PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I'm looking to learn Windows PowerShell. Can someone give me some really good references on where to start?

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33559/how-to-get-started-with-powershell

Comment: @EBGreen - I didn't see that one. It's closed. No fight this time ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search the web for some base tutorials on how to start.  Once you are comfortable branch into the sites showing examples.  Keep in mind that PowerShell is very similar to C# and uses the .net Framework.  Starting with these technologies will help further your learning in PowerShell.

PowerShell Pro
http://www.powershellpro.com/powershell-tutorial-introduction/

Basic Commands and Examples
http://weblogs.asp.net/steveschofield/archive/2007/01/25/basic-powershell-examples-couple-useful-commands.aspx

The PowerShell Guy
http://thepowershellguy.com/blogs/posh/archive/2007/03/31/powershell-examples-used-on-ars-technica.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I find that the podcast http://powerscripting.wordpress.com/ is pretty good. It won't teach you every bit of syntax you need to know but it's good as an introduction, if you use it start listening to the episodes from the beginning.